# Is there a Guide to Translate ArcPy code to GDAL equivalent?

Tags: arcpy, gdal

Due to cost-cutting measures I've been asked if I can migrate ArcPy code to a GDAL equivalent.

I'm fairly new to GIS, ArcPy, and GDAL.  Is there a website or guide which caters to providing equivalencies between ArcPy and GDAL?

I am not asking for any specific script examples tailored to geoprocessing shape files.  I'm looking for an overall guide.  Or something in that direction.